# Run a different text editor when i type in gedit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2, shortcut

I have recently fallen in love with Sublime Text 2 editor for windows and linux.

In windows I don't have this issue as much, as I don't work from the terminal as often, but I would REALLY like to fully replace `gedit` with `sublime` in my ubuntu 11.10 install.

I have replaced it as my default program for all text files, but one place I still have issues is the terminal. I have formed the habit of typing `gedit filename.txt &` from the command line. Unfortuntately typing in `sublime-text-2 filename.txt &` seems to take years longer and I would really appreciate the convenience of fully replacing the keyword `gedit` with `sublime-text-2`.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I know I can autocomplete to `sublime-text-2` with `subli` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, but the habit I have formed in typing `gedit` is not proving to be an easy one to break.

I figured since it's linux, anything is possible, but I am not sure where to start with configuing this. Thanks for any tips,

Comment: You could create an alias from gedit to sublime-text-2 in your bash profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use alias command and add to your .bash_profile

```
alias gedit='sublime-text-2'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just `alias` it, I guess.

But that seems a bizarre idea. I'd just change the habit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, alias does not permit to run the command in background while still passing argument. You can't do:

```
alias subl="/opt/Sublime/sublime_text $@ &"
```

You have to use a bash function, like this:

```
subl() { /opt/Subl2/sublime_text "$@" & }
```

add this to your bashrc and you will be able to start sublime text in detached mode and give file names to open.